# Why does my python ctypes code give incorrect results when passing a structure to a C++ shared library on Linux?

Tags: python, c++, linux, shared-libraries, ctypes

I use python and ctypes to pass one structure value to a c++ so.
But I got one incorrect value in the function.

**test.h**

```
#include <stdint.h>

#pragma pack (push, 1)
 
typedef struct
{    
    uint8_t a;
    int b;
}param;

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    bool b;
}intbool;
 
#pragma pack (pop)
extern "C" void set_struct_test(param params);
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include "test.h"
#include <stdio.h>
void set_struct_test(param params)
{ 
    printf("size:[%d]\n", sizeof(params));
    uint8_t* pdata = (uint8_t*)&params;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(params); i++)
    {
        printf("data[%d]:[%x]\n", i, pdata[i]);
    }
    printf("%s: %d %d\n", __FUNCTION__,params.a, params.b);
}
```

Build it as one dynamic library, and write a main.cpp to test it.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "HelloWorld/api.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
    param test_param;
    test_param.a = 8;
    test_param.b = 4;
    set_struct_test(test_param);
    return 0;
}
```

The print log is below, and it is correct.

```
size:[5]
data[0]:[8]
data[1]:[4]
data[2]:[0]
data[3]:[0]
data[4]:[0]
set_struct_test: 8 4
```

Then use the same 'so' file, and use python and ctypes to call it. the print log is incorrect.

**pytest.py**

```
from ctypes import *

class pyparam(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [("a", c_uint8),
                ("b", c_int32)]

class TestLib():
    def __init__(self):
        libpath = "xxx/HelloWorldLib.so"
        self.dll = cdll.LoadLibrary(libpath)
    
    def pyset_struct_test(self,params):
        ptr = pointer(params)
        raw_bytes = string_at(ptr, sizeof(params))
        print("test: ",raw_bytes)
        return self.dll.set_struct_test(params)    
  
helloworld = TestLib()

param = pyparam()
param.a = 8
param.b = 4
helloworld.pyset_struct_test(param)
```

the log is:

```
test:  b'\x08\x04\x00\x00\x00'
size:[5]
data[0]:[6]
data[1]:[0]
data[2]:[0]
data[3]:[0]
data[4]:[0]
set_struct_test: 6 0
```

The result is totolly incorrect.

I did not know what is wrong in my code.

who can help me to find the reason? I will very appreciate.

BTW I test the same code in different system. The result on Windows is right, but the result of Ubuntu is incorrect.

Comment: Is `set_struct_test` declared as `extern "C"`?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. This includes *complete* code that does *not* work, including compilation instructions, and a full set of error messages. If no error messages, the cose needs go print something. Explain why you think what it prints os wrong and what should it print instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [\[SO\]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546).

Comment: @n.m. thank you for your reply. the function is declared as extern C. The code example is so simple, just one library and python call. I will add more informations about the code.

Comment: `set_struct_test` doesn't match the output that shows `set_struct_boolint`. Always best to include the actual code you're testing in the question.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I reedit it, help it clear

Comment: @CristiFati it is not same. I tested sigle type value as the  parameter, that is correct. but use sturcture is different.

Comment: Did you set *argtypes*?

Comment: Code posted does work on Windows. Ubuntu might marshal the structure differently when passed by value instead of by reference. Make sure to set `self.dll.set_struct_test.argtypes = pyparam,` before calling `set_struct_test` and see if that helps.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Tested with **self.dll.set_struct_test.argtypes = [pyparam]**, but unfortunately the result is same.

Comment: Call your DLL from C then.  There's nothing incorrect about the Python code.  How are you building the .so?

Comment: @MarkTolonen use cmake build it. the CMakeList.txt : ``` aux_source_directory(. DIR_SRCS_LIB)  add_library(HelloWorldLib SHARED ${DIR_SRCS_LIB})```

Comment: Probably a deficiency of ctypes, it cannot pass packed structs by value. Pass by pointer or remove packing.